# Chart.js Version 1 differences and can they be achieved in version 2?

Tags: chart.js

I apologise if this is the wrong place but the chart.js git suggested this as the only place to get support.

I recently used version 1 of chart.js for a project and I picked this library over others because of the simpler/easier user experience. As an example the line graph, if you hover over an x axis it will highlight the closest points to your hover. In version 2 you have to hover over the actual point. It's a similar situation on the other graph types both in chart.js and other libraries like highcharts.js.

My question is simple, can we replicate the usability of version 1 in version 2 or have we lost this aspect completely?
Glancing at the documentation it doesn't appear to be possible.

If the answer is no, may I suggest that one of two things happen, either it's developed for version 2 or b version 1 is kept around.

Comment: Differences are amazing indeed. I could not use 
fill: false 
using version 1. I had to go to version 2 and promote various changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replicate the v1.x functionality by extending the `line` chart type and setting the tooltip mode to `label`, like so

```
Chart.defaults.myLine = Chart.helpers.clone(Chart.defaults.line);
Chart.controllers.myLine = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
    updateElement: function (point) {
        var result = Chart.controllers.line.prototype.updateElement.apply(this, arguments);
        point.inRange = function (mouseX, mouseY) {
            var vm = this._view;
            // ignore the y coordinate
            return vm ? (Math.abs(mouseX - vm.x) < (vm.hitRadius + vm.radius)) : false;
        };
        return result;
    }
});
```

and then

```
    ...
    type: 'myLine',
    ...
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'label'
        }
    }
};
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gyqmbL2q/

Comment: Can you set the distance around the line with pointHitDetectionRadius like in v1? Your answer makes it much better but it still requires mouse precision.

Comment: Yep, just look for `point.hitRadius` in http://www.chartjs.org/docs/. See http://jsfiddle.net/m0vrqtg5/

Comment: Excellent, I wish there was a simpler way of doing this but extending it does indeed work. I hope the devs see this and consider making this a simple option to toggle.